# Java LWJGL OGG Background Music

Tags: java, stream, lwjgl, playback, ogg

In my game I've have got a very long ogg files(about 8 to 20 mb) and some other machines aren't able to read it direct into memory. So I read that some games uses stream and play method. Is there any lib/code example to load and play ogg files(with LWJGL) in real time?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: As a general note, you want to compress files as much as you can in your game. 20MB for a single music track is simply unacceptable from the point of how long it would take to download your game.

Comment: My mistake, my background sound is about 5 min long(~9 mb) :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically need to play OGG files? If not, there are plenty of online converters than can convert it to MP3, WAV, etc.

Also, do you specifically need to play it with LWJGL? This is very possible with default java, like so:

```
static String randomName = "TreasureQuest";
public static Clip clip = null;
public static void playSound(String name) throws Exception{
    if (clip != null && clip.isOpen()) clip.close();
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("music/" + name + ".wav").getAbsoluteFile());
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        FloatControl gainControl = 
                (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            gainControl.setValue(0f);

        System.out.println(clip.getFrameLength() + " | " + clip.getFramePosition());
        clip.start();


}
```

Personally, I use this for my LWJGL game, and it works perfectly fine.

If you must play an OGG file, and you specifically must play it with LWJGL, I suggest you use OpenAL. [You can find the documentation for playing OGG files here](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=755.5;wap2).

Answer (score 0):

@Joehot200
So I have two music engines - java clip and lwjgl, so it doesn't metter which one i will be using :)

I have a very similar code to yours(but it includes ogg decompression) and it time loading is still very long - I want to read my sound file and play what I read at the same time(like YOUTUBE). Here is my piece of code:

```
public static Clip DecodeOgg(String filename)
{
    try
    {
        File file = new File(filename);
        // Get AudioInputStream from given file.
        AudioInputStream in= AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        AudioInputStream din = null;
        if (in != null)
        {
            AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
            AudioFormat  decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(
                    AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                    16,
                    baseFormat.getChannels(),
                    baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                    false);
            // Get AudioInputStream that will be decoded by underlying VorbisSPI
            din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);

            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(din);

            return clip;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you specifically need to load OGG? I have a 5 minute music track in my game loaded by the exact same code I posted above in WAV format. Moreover, it is loaded almost instantly.

Comment: I need a compressed music file(for one location in my game I have two long ogg files - for day and night) and the diffrence between 8mb and 80mb is huge. The problem is that I load my decompressed ogg file into memory and then play it. That is the real problem...